# MHD Shock Waves

Tags: python-2.7, scipy, physics

I need to solve these six equations (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shocks_and_discontinuities_(magnetohydrodynamics)) for MHD shock waves condition using scipy.fsolve. There are 6 unknown variables whose values need to be stored in the array z. While I am getting correct answers for some cases, in most cases the values are wrong. They vary according to the initial guess, what would be the correct initial guess so that it works for all cases. 
Note- z[0] and z[1] denote pressure and density and can't be negative. So a correct answer will give positive values.

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve, root
from scipy.constants import mu_0 as w

print("Assume the shock propogates in the x direction")
p1=float(input("Upstream pressure-"))
rho1=float(input("Upstream density-"))
vx1=float(input("Upstream velocity along x axis-"))
vy1=float(input("Upstream velocity along y axis-"))
bx1=float(input("Upstream magnetic field along x axis-"))
by1=float(input("Upstream magnetic field along y axis-"))


def eqn(x):                                 #jump conditions

    f1=(x[1]*x[2])-(rho1*vx1)
    f2=x[0]+(x[1]*x[2]*x[2])+(x[5]*x[5]*0.5/w)-p1-(rho1*vx1*vx1)-by1*by1*0.5/w
    f3=(x[1]*x[2]*x[3]-x[4]*x[5]/w)-rho1*vx1*vy1+bx1*by1/w
    f4= x[4]-bx1
    f5=x[2]*x[5]-x[4]*x[3]-vx1*by1+vy1*bx1
    f6=x[1]*x[2]*(0.5*(x[2]**2+x[3]**2) +2.5*x[0]/x[1]) +x[2]*(x[5]**2)/w -x[4]*x[5]*x[3]/w - rho1*vx1*(0.5*(vx1**2+vy1**2) +2.5*p1/rho1) -(vx1*by1**2)/w + bx1*by1*vy1/w

    return(f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,f6)

y=[2*p1,4*rho1,0.5,0.5,bx1*2,by1*2]                     #initial guess value

z=fsolve(eqn,y)


print '\n','Upstream Pressure- ',p1,'\t'*3,'Downstream Pressure- ',z[0]
print 'Upstream Density- ',rho1,'\t'*4,'Downstream Density- ',z[1] 
print 'Upstream velocity along x axis- ',vx1,'\t'*2,'Downstream velocity along x axis- ',z[2]
print 'Upstream velocity along y axis- ',vy1,'\t'*2,'Downstream velocity along y axis- ',z[3]
print 'Upstream magnetic field along x axis- ',bx1,'\t','Downstream magnetic field along x axis- ',z[4]
print 'Upstream magnetic field along y axis- ',by1,'\t','Downstream magnetic field along y axis- ',z[5]
```

Comment: Again, following on from your previous question, you must make an effort to use more descriptive variable names. It is very difficult to interpret (and even just to decipher) what the various `x[i]` mean.

Comment: x[i] are basically the unknown variables whose value I need to find. So according to the equations (refer to the link) and creating analogy with the variables whose value is user defined :- x[0]= p2, x[1]=rho2, x[2]=vx2 or vn2(same thing),x[3]=vy2 or vt2, x[4]=bx2 or bn2, x[5]=by2 or bt2. Hence, fsolve should solve these six equations to find the values of x[i] and the final answer shall be stored in an array defined as z. Hope that made it a bit clearer.